# Android Timer stops after updating TextView

Tags: java, android, timer, textview

i am trying to update a TextView every 5 seconds with a random number.
Unfortunately the timer stops when i call the .setText-function (i commented it out, it is because of this specific statement). I call the Timer in the onCreate()-Method of the Activity.

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Random r = new Random();
            count = r.nextInt(10);
            String degree = Integer.toString(count);
            mDegrees.setText(degree);
            showToast();
        }
    }
            , 1, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Also showToast() is not called. Why is that?

Best regards,

Max

Comment: I think you will need to run the `mDegrees.setText(degree);` statement on the UI thread.

Comment: Thank you very much, Titus! That's the thing i was missing!